# How to plot spectral indices $n_s$ and $r$ from Planck data?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, cosmological-inflation, data-analysis

From a certain inflationary model I have obtained the theoretical values for the spectral indices $n_s$ and $r$ as functions of $N$, the e-folds number of inflation. At this point it would be interesting to compare my results with those of other models and observational results. Basically I want to achieve something like this:

[image: ns and r plot]

Mainly I'm interested in the experimental results from Planck 2015. However, I don't know where to find the data on the [Planck archive](http://pla.esac.esa.int/pla/#home) corresponding to the blue and red regions of the image I posted.

Can someone please explain me where to find the data and how to plot it?